# Aplicación de escritorio vieja instalada en windows 10 no puedo encontrar su archivo de base de datos access

Tags: ms-access, windows10, vb

Tengo una aplicación de gestión de un colegio hecha en visual basic hace más de 10 años que usa base de datos de access. Cuando la instalo en win 10 lo hace en la carpeta archivos de programa(x86)
y en la carpeta del programa solo aparecen 2 archivos, el ejecutable: gestionAlumnos.exe y un .LOG. El programa funciona y si doy de alta una familia la guarda correctamente, cierro el programa lo abro nuevamente y la familia sigue estando cuando la busco. El tema es que no encuentro por ningún lado la base de datos y no se le puede hacer copia de seguridad, además hay que exportar la base de datos a un sistema de gestión nuevo pero no se puede por el mismo motivo. Lo primero que hice fue habilitar la vista de archivos ocultos y de sistema, busqué en la ruta c:\usuarios...\appData, entre otras muchas (En system32 y otras de archivos de programa(x86) y no aparece por ningún lado. Cuando el programa estaba instalado en una pc con windows 7 en el mismo directorio de instalación del programa aparecía el archivo de base de datos con extención .mdb, pero en windows 10 es imposible encontrarlo. Solicito ayuda por favor ya que es muy importante poder recuperar la información y muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: si sabes como se llama el archivo, porque no lo buscas en todo el disco y listo? seguro ya lo habrias encontrado ;)

Comment: En el administrador de tareas en la parte de abajo esta la opcion "Adminiqtrador de rendimiento o recursos. Ingresas allí y vas a la pestaña CPU ubicas el proceso que estás ejecutando y al seleccionarlo debería salirte en la parte inferior los recursos que utiliza. Allí deberías encontrar el archivo de base de datos. Si no puedes hacerlo entonces tendrás que instalas el ProcessExplorer que te permite hacer lo que indico. Raro que puedas instalar el programa sin saber dónde pone las cosas. Instalo con un usuario común a ver si te reclama derechos sobre algun directorio

Comment: Y en archivo de log no sale lo que buscas. Lo has abierto?

Comment: Hola. No en el .log ya me había fijado y no había nada que indicara la ruta de la B de D. Lo resolví con el Process Monitor que me recomendaron más abajo. Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se trata de saber qué ficheros está utilizando tu programa.
Descarga la aplicación ["Process Monitor" de SysInternals (de MIcrosoft)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Pon en marcha tu aplicación (**gestionAlumnos.exe**), ejecuta el Process Monitor y aplica un nuevo filtro para el programa que deseas rastrear. En tu caso que el ***ProcessName sea igual a gestionAlumnos.exe***.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez filtrados los procesos, deberías identificar en la lista el tuyo.
Guarda una familia o cualquier otra operación sobre tu programa y en la lista deberían aparecer las operaciones realizadas sobre el registro, ficheros,...

En mi caso, por ejemplo, mi programa utiliza un fichero de texto. Al realizar operaciones sobre él, aparecen como: **CreateFile**, **ReadFile**,...  y el path sobre el fichero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esa lista (si es que la utiliza) debería aparecer tu fichero de Base de Datos de MSAccess.

Comment: Hola. Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda. Lo probé en mi PC y encontré la base de datos. Ahora tengo que hacerlo en la PC del colegio que es donde está lo que importa. Luego te comento. Nuevamente gracias.

Comment: Ya lo hice en la PC del colegio con la base de datos verdadera y funcionó. Muchisimas gracias.

Comment: @PabloComerci si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor, márcala como correcta para que se cierre la pregunta y sirva a futuros lectores. Mira [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas)